# JMeter, BeanShell Assertion comparison multiple iterations

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell

I have a problem. In my test case, every iteration has a response different or different number variables, depends on data input. Example. The first iteration responds one code and one description; the Second iteration responds two codes and two descriptions; and similar. I need insert a BeanShell Assertion to validate the response every iteration.
First step: add a TWO Regular Expression Extractor (one for each variable)
[image: Regular Expression for "clave"]

[image: Regular Expresion for "Descripcion"]

My code in BeanShell Assertion not working; only extract the first value for each RegEx Extractor

```js
String Resp_clave_g1 = vars.get("Resp_clave_g1"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_descripcion_g1 = vars.get("Resp_descripcion_g1"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_clave_g2 = vars.get("Resp_clave_g2"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_descripcion_g2 = vars.get("Resp_descripcion_g2"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_clave_g3 = vars.get("Resp_clave_g3"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_descripcion_g3 = vars.get("Resp_descripcion_g3"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_clave_g4 = vars.get("Resp_clave_g4"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_descripcion_g4 = vars.get("Resp_descripcion_g4"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_clave_g5 = vars.get("Resp_clave_g5"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_descripcion_g5 = vars.get("Resp_descripcion_g5"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_clave_g6 = vars.get("Resp_clave_g6"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor
String Resp_descripcion_g6 = vars.get("Resp_descripcion_g6"); //Obtained from Regular Expresion Extractor

log.warn (Resp_clave_g1);
log.warn (Resp_descripcion_g1);
log.warn (Resp_clave_g2);
log.warn (Resp_descripcion_g2);
log.warn (Resp_clave_g3);
log.warn (Resp_descripcion_g3);
log.warn (Resp_clave_g4);
log.warn (Resp_descripcion_g4);
log.warn (Resp_clave_g5);
log.warn (Resp_descripcion_g5);
log.warn (Resp_clave_g6);
log.warn (Resp_descripcion_g6);

if (Resp_clave_g1 != null && Resp_clave_g1.equals("${clave_1}") == false){ //Obtained from DataSet CSV
  Failure = true;
 FailureMessage = "Not a valid string, expected: ${clave_1}, actual value: " + Resp_clave_g1;
}else{
 Failure = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed changing `Match No.` to negative number as -1 to return [all occurrences](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)

> If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but it's not working for me by placing -1 in match No.
It works if I put $ 1 $ in Template and nothing in Match No., but it only calls the first value of the Regular Expression Extractor when invoking it with Resp_clave_g1, the invocation with Resp_clave_g2 brings me null value in the log; unless it is not invoked with * _g2, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: I could do!!
Indeed, I only had to change the invocation, not with *_g1, but with * _1 only.
I greatly appreciate the help @user7294900.